# Receiving and processing continous packets using UDP

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, asynccallback

This is my current setup (using UDP):

```
void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    byte[] buffer = socket.EndReceive(result, ref ep);

    Packet p = new Packet(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

    //process packet

    socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), socket);

}
```

I was wondering what would happen if I immediately call socket.BeginReceive after calling EndReceive and then process the packet to obtain a continous packet flow like this:

```
void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    byte[] buffer = socket.EndReceive(result, ref ep);
    socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), socket);

    Packet p = new Packet(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

    //process packets

}
```

If a packet is received as soon as I call BeginReceive, would this conflict with the current packet processing somehow?

Also if this would not conflict would changing to TCP make this disfunctional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are creating some sort of recursive handler there. I am unsure how that will work, probably not in a good way. I usually go for a separate reader thread that listens to incoming data and passes it on to an event. This has served me well in the past. I have not looked into using async for this though.

Here is some example code on how to use a separate thread to handle incoming UDP data. It is not complete but should give you an idea of how to set it up.

```
    private Thread _udpReadThread;
    private volatile bool _terminateThread;

    public event DataEventHandler OnDataReceived;
    public delegate void DataEventHandler(object sender, DataEventArgs e);

    private void CreateUdpReadThread()
    {
        _udpReadThread = new Thread(UdpReadThread) { Name = "UDP Read thread" };
        _udpReadThread.Start(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
    }

    private void UdpReadThread(object endPoint)
    {
        var myEndPoint = (EndPoint)endPoint;
        var udpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        udpListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        // Important to specify a timeout value, otherwise the socket ReceiveFrom() 
        // will block indefinitely if no packets are received and the thread will never terminate
        udpListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 100);
        udpListener.Bind(myEndPoint);

        try
        {
            while (!_terminateThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    var size = udpListener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref myEndPoint);
                    Array.Resize(ref buffer, size);

                    // Let any consumer(s) handle the data via an event
                    FireOnDataReceived(((IPEndPoint)(myEndPoint)).Address, buffer);
                }
                catch (SocketException socketException)
                {
                    // Handle socket errors
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close Socket
            udpListener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            udpListener.Close();
        }
    }

    public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public byte[] Data { get; private set; }
        public IPAddress IpAddress { get; private set; }

        public DataEventArgs(IPAddress ipaddress, byte[] data)
        {
            IpAddress = ipaddress;
            Data = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be a valid answer but I can't vote it up due to my reputation of 11. 

The approach I am currently using is Socket.BeginReceive which calls the function bound in the new AsyncCallback argument when data has been received. (I believe this allows the current call to OnDataReceived to finish while at the same time being able to listen for new data) 
My main concern is probably a bit silly but I'm worried about how multiple calls to 1 function from several threads works when it's done simultaneously

Comment: Actually disregard that, I kind of found a solution to it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467070/multiple-threads-calling-the-same-function

Comment: Doesn't this cause a lot of needless memory reallocation?  You allocate your buffer every pass around the loop whether it's used or not.

Comment: Yes, you can optimize things here slightly by allocating only when something has been received.